# pymongo update creates a new record without upserting

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have an issue where I do an update on a document, however, the update creates a new document and I'm *not* upserting in my update.

This is my testing code.
I do a find to see if the document exists by checking if "lastseen" doesn't exist:

```
result = DATA_Collection.find({"sessionID":"12345","lastseen":{"$exists":False}})
if result.count() == 1:
   DATA_Collection.update({"sessionID":"12345"},{"$set":{"lastseen":"2021-05-07"}})
```

When I do an aggregate check to find duplicates I get a few, one example below.

```
> db.DATA_Collection.find({ "sessionID" : "237a5fb8" })

{ "_id" : ObjectId("60bdf7b05c961b4d27d33bde"), "sessionID" : "237a5fb8", "firstseen" : ISODate("1970-01-19T20:51:09Z"), "lastseen" : ISODate("2021-06-07T12:34:20Z") }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("60bdf7fa7d35ea0f046a2514"), "sessionID" : "237a5fb8", "firstseen" : ISODate("1970-01-19T20:51:09Z") }
```

I remove all the records in the collection and rerun the script, the same happens again.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your pymongo commands are deprecated; use `update_one()` or `update_many()` instead of `update()`; `count_documents()` instead of `count()`.

Secondly double check you are referencing the same collections as you mention `DATA_Collection` and `VPN_DATA`;

How are you defining a "duplicate"? Unless you create a unique index on the field(s), the records won't be duplicates as they have different `_id` fields.

You need something like:

```
record = db.VPN_DATA.find_one({'sessionID': '12345', 'lastseen': {'$exists': False}})

if record is not None:
    db.VPN_DATA.update_one({'_id': record.get('_id')}, {'$set': {'lastseen': '2021-05-07'}})
```

Comment: Hi Belly. The `VPN _Data` is a typo, it is `DATA_Collection` on both. I do have a unique index created on sessions, is this the cause?  I have corrected the collection names in the post.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?